# Is there any reliable way to identify the user machine in a unique way?

Tags: php, mysql, html

What is the best way to make sure a login in a PHP website is only valid to a certain machine?

Currently I have a system which validates certain usernames/passwords, although if several people have that password all of them can login successfully.

Is there any reliable way to identify the user machine in a unique way?
I have been considering some alternatives, doing this by cookies usage, or maybe localstorage?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The short answer to this question is: **No**. And it's very good it is this way.

Comment: Why exactly is this tagged with HTML5 or MYSQL tag since it's obviously a PHP question?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith: Because of localstorage suggestion ;)